# Pygame input which isn't keyboard/mouse

Tags: pygame

Is there any way to accept input into a pygame event loop which isn't from an keyboard/mouse event? I'm creating a game which receives input from a chat room and I want to send those inputs into the main loop to be handled as they come in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use `pygame.event.post()` to post your own [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) object. See [`pygame.event.post()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.post)

> Places the given event at the end of the event queue.
> This is usually used for placing `pygame.USEREVENT` events on the queue. [...]